# Issue with the bool tool

Tags: modifiers, shaders

[image]

This has been driving me crazy! The included picture explains more.

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Text in images is not searchable. Please [write out your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/199343/edit) in the text field of your question so  that search engines and future users with the same problem can find this Q (and answer when it arrives). Thanks :)

Comment: The bool tool often creates "ugly" geometry that can cause shading issues (such as tris or n-gons). You may have to re-topologize (manually or otherwise) to make sure your geometry is nice and neat (quad only, especially on curved surfaces).

Comment: hard to help without seeing the wireframe, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/